# custom brush landmass (UE5 landscape tool)

Tags: unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

Is it possible that the custombrush_landmass procedural effect only applies to a certain landscape component? Imagine my landscape has four component and I want the landmass brush to effect only one of them and not interfere with the other three! imagine something like a mask that stops the brush from effecting the other part of the landscape. Thank you in advance!

https://ibb.co/dpHh5Yq

i tried , layers and masking with selection tool in landscape mode, it doesn't worked, and also the layer system work somehow but it keep deleting the last layer so it doesn't give me a full control.